# Why is hot reloading not working in Vite + Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, vite

I created a rails app, and installed vite_rails gem. My javascript is in app/frontend folder.

However, hot reloading when I save a JS file is not working.

I also tried by installing vite-plugin-full-reload NPM package. This is my config for vite:

```js
// vite.config.js
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import FullReload from 'vite-plugin-full-reload'
import RubyPlugin from 'vite-plugin-ruby'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    RubyPlugin(),
    vue(),
    FullReload(['config/routes.rb', 'app/views/**/*', 'app/frontend/**/*']),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./app/frontend/internal', import.meta.url)),
    },
  },
})
```

Docker config:

```yaml
# docker-compose.yml
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    env_file: .env.development
  web:
    image: rails
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    env_file: .env.development
```

```
FROM ruby:3.3

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential apt-utils libpq-dev nodejs npm

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN gem install bundler rails && bundle

CMD rm tmp/pids/server.pid && rails s -b 0.0.0.0
```

Still not reloading, why?

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in your browser console? How are you running the app and vite? Native or in a container? It's most likely an issue with ports, http/https, or your content security policy.

Comment: I'm using docker, and I configured 3000 and 5173 ports, but vite does not detect any changes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example from a working docker-compose.yml with vite-dev:

```
  app:
    build:
      context: .
    depends_on:
      - database
      - redis
      - vite
    entrypoint: ./entrypoints/docker-entrypoint.sh
    command: ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      RAILS_ENV: development
      DOCKER: true
      VITE_RUBY_HOST: vite
      VITE_RUBY_PORT: 5173
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true

  vite:
    build:
      context: .
    entrypoint: ./entrypoints/docker-vite.sh
    environment:
      DEBUG: '*vite*'
      RAILS_ENV: development
      VITE_RUBY_HOST: 0.0.0.0
      VITE_RUBY_PORT: 5173
    ports:
      - 5173:5173
```

The entrypoints/docker-vite.sh is just this:

```
#!/bin/sh

yarn install
bin/vite dev
```

Comment: I have just added my docker config to the question. vite_rails gem starts vite automatically. Should I stop it from doing that? And how?